# NTFS config and startup mounting

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have installed Xubuntu 14.04 64bit version. And then I have installed ntfs config. But at that time my external storage(HDD) was connected with my laptop. Then I have restarted my laptop but that time I disconnected my external storage. And this is the problem that in the time of start-up this OS is giving message "the storage is not ready or can't mount. wait to continue S to skip, M to manual config" Like that. But I don't want this message to show me and the OS to check the external device and to mount. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a reference to the external drive in your bootloader (grub) or in the fstab. I bet it's in the fstab.

Boot and check if the file `/etc/fstab` contains a reference to your external drive, the relevant line may have `ntfs` in it. Then edit that file (`nano /etc/fstab`) and delete that line, save, and reboot. The message should now be gone.